# develop Windows 7 gadgets.Need to extract text from a website

Tags: javascript, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I want to develop a **Windows 7 gadgets** in which I need to extract some text(to be specific a list) from a website.Is there any way to get this done using JavaScript?

How could i possible do it?

Is there any website or book to help me develop Windows 7 gadgets?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an API or else you would have to code an html parser that is WAY overkill for what you need. What information are you trying to get?

Comment: I want to extract a list of names from a website(list is ranking of a some people.It contain their Name,Rank and Score.Which is updated every day midnight)